# Set Environment=Development when xunit testing an ASP.NET Core app

Tags: asp.net-core, xunit.net

I `xUnit` test my ASP.NET Core web app, and my test class includes:

```
this.host = Program.CreateHostBuilder(Array.Empty<string>()).Build();
```

in order to access `host.Services`.

I discover that the host has `Environment=Production`. So the configuration seen in my startup file ignores `appsettings.Development.json`.

How do I inject or force host to have `Environment=Development`?

Preferably without any code in the web app itself.

(Context: I'm using JetBrains Rider. I find nothing in Rider setup or configuration that lets me choose an Environment for a UnitTest session. But if there is a solution on that line the question still stands)

Answer (score 1):

I had assumed—wrongly—that I might fix it with this:

```
this.host = Program.CreateHostBuilder(
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development"
    ).Build();
```

because [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#default) say

> The default configuration loads environment variables and command line arguments prefixed with DOTNET_ and ASPNETCORE_

but what fixed it was:

```
this.host = Program.CreateHostBuilder(
    "ENVIRONMENT=Development"
    ).Build();
```

With this, the Configuration element then picked up the `appsettings.Development.json` file instead of ignoring it.

( So now I wonder whether part of the env variable processing is done by the dotnet executable before reaching `Program.Main()` )